# Trouble with Api Symfony relation OnetoOne

Tags: reactjs, symfony, api-platform.com

I created a back API with Symfony and a front with React. To communicate between back and front I'm using API PLATFORM.

I created in Symfony one entity "users" and one entity "customers" with a relation OneToOne. In React when I create a new Customer I automatically create a new User for the same person. This works perfectly.

In my table Customer a column "user_id" has been automatically created by the relation. In this column I find the id of user which corresponds to the customer.

Via react I need to do a request with API Platform in direction of the Entity User to find the id of the customer which corresponds to the User. I don't have a column client_id because I made the relation OneToOne in the client entity.

I can't find the solution.

Comment: Please share a [mre] showing your entities and their relations. It is possible to hydrate a linked entity via API Platform, or also possible to include an IRI for the linked entity making it possible for the front end to request it.

Comment: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/subresources/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to complete your entity, by default a OneToOne relation is not bidirectionnal, adding cascade persist and above all JoinColumn on the two sides:

```php
class Customer
{
     /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="customer", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $user;

    // getters / setters
}

class User
{
    /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Customer::class, mappedBy="customer", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL"))
    */
    private $customer;

    // getters / setters
}
```

then launch the command to create the migration:

```sh
php bin/console d:m:diff
```